# Visual Studio SSIS Variable Window not displaying not working as expected

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I have 2019 VS with SSIS installed. For some reason, the variable window is no longer allowing me to see the existing variables nor create new variables. Below is the window of the variable when I open it.

[image]

Comment: try starting visual studio using `devenv.exe /safemode` command. Also try to open the Variables tab by pressing mouse right click in the package control flow, and click on `Variables`

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem on two different machines. @cookiemonster were you able to solve this? If you I open VS with the safemode switch, I can't even load SSIS projects.

Comment: Am able to load SSIS projects but still the issue persists.

Comment: Try upgrading the SSIS version. Upgrading it help to restore the window.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem, and remedied it by installing the SQL Server Integration Services Projects update as recommended by the Developer Community.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/581038/ssis-variables-window-is-transparent-in-vs-2019-16.html